# Mac Chrome ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for local domain that was previously located in another server

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dns, localhost, local

I was testing out local environments and with DesktopServer I created a WordPress site with the domain "groundedaerial.local". I shut down DesktopServer and started to play with Local by Flywheel. I created a local domain with the same name. When I try to view the domain in Chrome, I get: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Safari can go to the domain.

I have tried flushing Chrome's DNS cache, sockets, and the browser cache. None work. I created another website with a completely unique name and it opens in Chrome.  I have reset my routers and restarted by MacBook. Still no luck. I have ran commands in terminal that according to other help articles flush a local DNS cache.

I realize I could name it something else, but I'd rather not. And I have some other resources set up locally to interact with that domain.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if port 443 is being used by any application, I had this same issue and ran through all the help available (restart databases, confirm Skype is not running, etc) and it was actually VMWare using port 443. Once I killed it, the localhost site displaying all desktop server sites had loaded correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Using Terminal type in following:

```
  /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=~/.chrome_dev_session --disable-web-security &
```

This will launch Chrome with security disabled. You may get the chrome security notice the first time you visit the local domain. You may also need to have a self signed SSL certificate.